# Having an issue wit git bash on Window 10 a recent change has stopped me from being able to update up it

Tags: windows-10, git-bash

I have the Git version 2.31.1.windows.1 installed and have tied re-installing it.  I made a change to it to add a new alias.  One I did I tried to source the file to reload it and received this error.

**bash: /c/Users/DawsonSchaffer/.bashrc: Bad address**

So I restored my previous version, which was working fine. However I still get the same error now.  I know this isn't a lot of here is my .bashrc file

```
# History settings
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
shopt -s histappend
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=10000
HISTTIMEFORMAT="%F %T "

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
force_color_prompt=yes
if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
        # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
        # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
        # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
        color_prompt=yes
    else
        color_prompt=
    fi
fi

# load color variables
if [ -f ~/.bash_colors ]; then
    . ~/.bash_colors
fi

# prompt
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1="${GREEN}ganymede@${BLUE}dawson:${ICYAN}\W${RESET}${IYELLOW} \$(parse_git_branch) $ " 
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# get current branch in git repo
parse_git_branch() {
     git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ (\1)/'
}

# function parse_git_branch() {
#   BRANCH=`git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/\1/'`
#   if [ ! "${BRANCH}" == "" ]
#   then
#       STAT=`parse_git_dirty`
#       echo "[${BRANCH}${STAT}]"
#   else
#       echo ""
#   fi
# }

# file colors
LS_ORIGINAL=LS_COLORS
LS_COLORS='di=93:*.py=92:*.qml=92sb'
export LS_COLORS

# Alias definitions.
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# Alias functions.
if [ -f ~/.bash_functions ]; then
    . ~/.bash_functions
fi

# virtual environment home
export WORKON_HOME='C:\Users\DawsonSchaffer\Documents\ProjectsDirectory\virtualenvirinments'
```

Any help would greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Dawson

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, after scanning the files several times I finally found that I had a funky character in my .bashrc once I removed it every is working perfectly.

Thanks
Dawson